# How can I use Aurelia Fetch Client to query an API protected by Windows Authentication?

Tags: aurelia-fetch-client, aurelia

We have a web server serving our Aurelia static files as well as an API, the server is protected by *NTLM* (using *Integrated Windows Authentication* on *OWIN*).

When using the **Aurelia Fetch Client** we can successfully hit the API with not problem. Here's the config we use:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient){
        http.configure(config => {
            config
            .withBaseUrl('api/')
            .useStandardConfiguration();
        });
```

However when we use the **Aurelia Fetch Client** we get the `401 (Unauthorized)` (seems the authorization header is missing)

```
constructor(private client: HttpClient) {
        client.configure(cfg => {
            cfg
            .withBaseUrl('http://localhost:80/api/someEndpoint')
            .withDefaults({
                headers: {
                    'Accept' : 'application/json',
                    'X-Requested-With': 'Fetch'
                }
            })
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turned out I was missing the `credentials`:

```
constructor(private client: HttpClient) {
        client.configure(cfg => {
            cfg
            .withBaseUrl('http://localhost:80/someEndpoint')
            .withDefaults({
                credentials: 'same-origin',
                headers: {
                    'Accept' : 'application/json',
                    'X-Requested-With': 'Fetch'
                }
            })
```